# How to use Laravel as the backend for an Angular SPA app?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel, api

I would like to create a website with Angular (frontend) and Laravel (backend).
What is the best way to connect these two? How do they communicate? 
What I found while searching was more than 2 years old solutions, so I am wondering if there is a preferred way to do that now.

**What I do right now:** 
I created Model, Controller and Migration files in laravel, and in **LanguagesController** I call the "::all" method to get all the data from XAMPP:

```
public function index()
{

    return response()->json(Languages::all(), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8'],
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

}
```

After that I create route for it in **api.php**:

```
Route::get('/languages', "LanguagesController@index");
```

So now, I can call www.laravelfirsttry.com/api/languages to get all the data from Languages table.

**In Angular, I did the following:** 
Create a **language-service** which send a request to Laravel:

```
private baseUrl = 'http://www.laravelfirsttry.com/api/languages';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getLanguages() {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
}
```

Then in my **component** I call this service, and give its function's response to my variable then I just handle the view after that:

```
constructor(private languageService: LanguageService) { 
this.getLanguages();
}
getLanguages(): void{
this.languageService.getLanguages()
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.language_tabs = res;
    console.log(res);
  }, error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

But the problem is that when I try it, the api call takes **relatively long time to finish**. I load my website, all the content is loaded, but the main component is not visible until the call is finished. I think this does not look good, and I think I did something wrong.

**Summary**: I created one **API** in **laravel**, then I call this API in **Angular**, and its quite slow. What is the best way to make an Angular application with Laravel backend?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need HttpClientModule to the imports array of your AppModule,
something like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then import httpClient in your component and add it to the constructor

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Then you can call API with code like this.

```
this.http.get<any>('http://www.laravelfirsttry.com/api/languages').subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            // do any operations with your data.
        })
```

As a pre-requisite Please make sure that your backend Laravel API is working fine.